# Array not being recognized

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm not really sure how to explain this, but basically, I have an input that takes in text. However, when I enter text that formatted exactly like an array, the program doesn't recognize it as an array, but rather a string.

How do I make my program recognize that my input is an array?

I input my value here:

```
<input id="inputArray" type="text" style="width:50%" placeholder="Your Array" oninput="storeArray(this.value)" onchange="storeArray(this.value)">
```

I store my value using the middleArray variable.

```
function storeArray(value) { //stores the input value
   middleArray = value;
   console.log(middleArray);
}
```

MiddleArray thinks that I have a string entered instead of an array even when the text is formated like an array.

What should I do to make the program recognize my input as an array?

Comment: A string that looks like an array is still a string.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure what exactly you're trying to do here. If you want to detect that the entered text is an array, you can do a `JSON.parse` on the value, because the value fetched from the input box will always be a string.

```
function storeArray(value) {
   middleArray = JSON.parse(value);
   console.log(middleArray); // Will be an array
}
```

Note that the function above tries to parse the string as a JS object (array in your case). It may result in an error if you try to parse an invalid object string representation. You can always try to do a dirty checking before parsing, or use `try-catch` blocks to mitigate any error:

```
function storeArray(value) {
   value = value.trim();
   middleArray = null;

   if (value[0] === '[' && value[value.length - 1] === ']') {
     middleArray = JSON.parse(value);
   }

   console.log(middleArray);
}
```

Comment: Oh! Thank you so much!

Comment: @Devin if the answer helped you then please accept it as a solution.